# Cannot improve the accuracy of my Multilayer Perceptron (MLP) model in classification

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function, mlp

I am trying to predict labels for building performance: {1, 0}. Since this is a binary classification, I tried sigmoid and identity activation functions with Xavier initialization. However, I cannot improve the accuracy of my models as the loss and accuracy stay still after training each epoch. This is a very imbalanced dataset where the ones have the 90% majority. So, I assume this might be due to the initial bias. Can you help me with this one? You can see the setup of the training process and the other relevant images attached.[model definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8You.png), [hyperparameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tF7k.png), [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOZZk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here are several suggestions which may help:

1. Use activation after **each** hidden layer
2. Learning rate of 0.1 is too high for Adam. Try smaller (3e-4 for example)
3. You are printing loss value incorrectly. Currently loss value is taken for the last iteration only. Calculate mean epoch loss instead.
4. Minor suggestion: since the task is binary classification it's better to apply `torch.nn.BCELoss` or `torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` if you don't use sigmoid on last layer. Last linear layer must have output_size=1 in this case.
5. Best model checkpoint may be missed with code you provided. That's because you calculate accuracy each 10 epochs, however `accuracy > best_accuracy` is done on each epoch which is inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I applied your suggestions one by one except the loss function. Because if I change to BCE loss, the output sizes do not match since I am dealing with two classes. And I get this error: "ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([2])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.". Even though I changed the learning rate and displayed the errors for each epoch, I could not improve the accuracy.

Comment: and loss value is still the same for each epoch?

Comment: By the way, if you decided to use CrossEntropyLoss you'd better apply `torch.softmax(x, dim=1)` activation at the end

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I don't think the model is getting updated during training. The problem is more essential I supose.

Comment: If I apply softmax, the following error occurs: "IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)"

Comment: That's strange. Could you check what is the shape of `x_tr` batch?